# How to read different IV charts in the "component tester"?

Tags: oscilloscope, test-equipment, component-failure, tester

I am doing a "comparison test" of 2 cards with the component tester. My component tester has 4 different test modes. LOGIC, LOW, MED and HIGH. LOGIC (10V 10mA), LOW (10V 100mA), MED (20V 5mA) and HIGH (50 0.5mA). When I compare 2 cards (when I touch the probes to the same points), LOGIC displays the same IV graph on the screen on the oscilloscope screen in both MED and HIGH mode. But in LOW mode, the graphics are slightly different. Especially in the positive (zone 1) stretch part, the right side looks a little swollen.

The visuals are as follows.

[image]

The other card on LOW mode:

[image]

How to read this difference. I wonder which part of the circuit had an error. To be able to fix faster, first I need to check which parts. what could be the reason for this different graphic? can you help me.

[image]

Comment: Component testers aren't make to work on "cards."  They are made to work on single, bare components.  Testing a component in circuit will **not** provide useful results.

Comment: Jeez.  Just noticed the voltages and currents on that thing.  Do **not** connect that to random parts of PCBs containg ICs.  You run a very good chance of destroying things with over voltage and high current.  Put that thing down, and back away slowly.  Nobody needs to get hurt here.